# Several true/false statements about a finite group $a,g\in G$ such that $a$ is of order $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group, and $a,g\in G$ such that $a$ is of order $2$, then the following is either true or false:
>
> 1. The element $gag^{-1}$ is of order $2$.
> 2. $(ag)^2=g^2$
> 3. if $ag$ is of order $2$ then $gag = a$

So 1 is immediate for any abelian group, and I can't find any other group that will have an element of order 2, so it could be true.

For 2, I tried several groups and couldn't find a counter example, $ag$ always result in $g$, no idea how to prove it though...

For 3, since $ag$ and $a$ have the same order $2$, then $g=a$ (?) then $a^3=1\cdot a=a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You will have to think a little more. Show that $g a g^{-1} \ne 1$, and then compute $(g a g^{-1})^{2}$.
2. In $S_{3}$, take $a = (12)$ and $g = (123)$ and see what happens.
3. $a g$ of order $2$ implies $a g a g = 1$. Now multiply on the left by $a$.

Comment: The group of permutations on the set $\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$. An essential tool in any bag of (counter)examples.